# Form scaling issue on Chinese OS (96 dpi)

Tags: .net, winforms, localization, scaling, cjk

I have a sample .NET application which consists of 2 forms. I have used images and various controls over these forms. When I run this application under XP or Win 7 English version, it works fine. But, when I run this application under Chinese version OS, the form size changes. It increases the form size, causing distorted forms.

Is anybody aware of this issue? What can be done to resolve it?

Comment: It's most likely because of default system "varibles" (such as default font size, etc). I can't give any specific pointers, in my opinion the best thing to do would be to fix the form so it can scale without problems, but then again it might not be an option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried various options. To resolve this problem we need to set Forms

> AutoScaleMode

property to none. This resolves the problem for 96 dpi settings.

Answer (score 1):

Set the following properties for the Windows Form:

1. AutoScaleMode = None,
2. AutoSize = True.

This will do it.  Good Luck